# Can an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{q}[T]$ have multiple roots?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, function-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ be a finite field of order $q = p^{l}$ for some prime $p$ and $l \geq 1$ and consider the ring of polynomials $R = (\mathbb{F}_{q}[T])[x] $. Can an irreducible element $g(x)$ in $R$ have a multiple root?

Let $g$ be irreducible and $\alpha$ be its multiple root. Then $\alpha$ is also the root of the derivative $g^{\prime}$ and hence is also a root of gcd$(g, g^{\prime})$. Since $g$ is irreducible, we must have that gcd$(g, g^{\prime}) = g$. This forces $g^{\prime} = 0$ in $R$. In other words, $g (x) = h(x^{q}) = h(x)^{q} $ for a smaller degree polynomial $h$, which is a contradiction to the irreducibility of $g$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Seems correct to me. I wonder what $T$ is in the first sentence. I haven't come across that notation before.

Comment: That $T$ is apparently  transcendental over $\Bbb{F}_q$, and that changes things. What happens with $g(x)=x^p-T$? Its roots are in an extension field of the field of fractions $K:=Q(R)=\Bbb{F}_q(T)$. In other words, that $T$ moves you from [tag:finite-fields] to [tag:function-fields], and some "rules" change.

Comment: In particular, @JyrkiLahtonen's example $g(x)=x^p-T$ shows which step in the OP's proof is incorrect: $g'(x)=0$ indeed, but $g(x)$ is not of the form $h(x)^p$ in $\Bbb F_p[T]$.

Comment: $h(x^q)\ne h(x)^q$ in general.